# Implied volatility skew decay over expiry

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, volatility-skew

I seem to remember the implied volatility skew of European options decreases as the expiry increases. It is true for the Heston model under some approximation. What are the good references that prove this property in general, or at least asymptotically?

Comment: Formula 3.4 here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~rl/impvol.pdf